# How to calculate error in pre/post condition regression analysis?

Tags: statistics, regression

I'm comparing machinery upgrade data and evaluating the performance gain after a machinery upgrade.

I have data (GT Power, ST Power) for both pre and post conditions. These are my x=GT Power and Y = ST Power variables.

I ask this question, after the upgrade at the same GT Power (independent variable) how much did the ST power increase (dependent variable).

Having a regression analysis as show in the below table, I can take the difference of line pre and post for a one full year. From there I can estimate how much energy gain was achieved as a percentage or by calculating the differences of ST Power but with the GT Power of pre-condition.

In the graph the blue lines are pre data and green lines are post data. How can I express the error in my analysis as there are two regression analysis and both has an error. Also is my method the best way to do this comparison?

[image]

Comment: Would you please post a scatterplot of the data?